# Reactjs Dynamically call components having cards under tabpanels using array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jquery-ui-tabs

This is where Tab header and tab content is defined, expectation is Tabs_content has component name, and under tabpanel it should traverse array tabs_content and display component  < AddQueueCard /> and call the component shown in image 3

```js
let tabs_data= ['Add Queue','Edit Queue','Remove Queue'];
    let tabs_content= ['<AddQueueCard />','EditQueueCard','C content' ];
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active">
          <div>
               <div  id="test">
        <Tabs>
          <ul>
            <TabList>
              
            {tabs_data.map(i => (
                <Tab>{i}</Tab>
                  ))}`***enter code here***`
            </TabList>
            </ul>
            {tabs_content.map(i => (
            
                <TabPanel>
              {i}   {/* here I want to call cards dynamically like <AddQueueCard /> <EditQueueCard> if clicked on 1st or 2nd tab respectively. How do I do that */}
               </TabPanel> 
            
              ))}
          </Tabs>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          <div class="tab-pane">
      
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Currently cards are not called]
[image]
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass Component itself , but its better to have a separate component dictionary and loop through that for rendering dynamic component, don't mix component and other things in one array, if you did you have to find a way to detect that item is react component and then render it.

```
let tabs_data= ['Add Queue','Edit Queue','Remove Queue'];
let tabs_content= [AddQueueCard, EditQueueCard, 'C content'];

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
      <div>
        <div id="test">
          <Tabs>
            <ul>
              <TabList>
                {tabs_data.map((i) => (
                  <Tab>{i}</Tab>
                ))}
              </TabList>
            </ul>
            {tabs_content.map((Item) => {
              return <TabPanel>
                {typeof Item === "function" ? <Item /> : Item}
              </TabPanel>
            })}
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane"></div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

Comment: Perfect Worked like magic!! THANKS A LOT :D